# Mardi-Gras combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

A group of $8$ people decides to go to a masquerade in a $6-$floor palace. The people are masked in such way that they are indistinguishable one from another. Not knowing at which floor the party is, each person decides where to look for the party. In how many different ways can this happen?

Combinatorically speaking, this problem is giving me issues. I suppose that I should fix the number of floors which will be occupied and find in how many different ways people can distribute in this number of floors. This lead me to think that the formula should be something like $\sum_{i=1}^6 {6\choose{i}}*f(i)$, but I can't figure out how to work out a general expression for $f(i)$. Working it by cases did not really help much. Am I completely offroad?

I found the solution of the problem computationally with Python. This can be easily done noticing that the problem is equivalent to search for the cardinality of the solution set to the equation

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_6=8 $$ with $x_i \in \mathbb N$ and $0\leq x_i\leq 8$

The answer should be $1287$. What path should I choose to look for $f(i)$? Is there an easier approach to the problem which I am not considering?

Comment: Basically, you're putting 8 unlabelled balls into 6 labelled boxes?

Comment: So what they were saying about Ash Wednesday was true. Yes, indeed, the two problems are exactly the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is equivalent to this one:
Consider 8 unlabelled balls and 5 sticks, you're looking for all the way you can dispose that elements in a line. Pay attention that with 5 sticks you can create 6 groups of balls (eventually empty). 
You have 8+6-1 elements in total and 6 boxes to form, so your relation is: (8+6-1)!/((5)!*(8)!)
Speaking in general, if you have k unlabelled balls and n boxes, you have the following relation (n+k-1)!/(k!*(n-1)!)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by disposing sticks and unlabeled balls in a line. What do you mean by "with 5 sticks you can create 6 grousp of balls"?

Comment: Say 2 people look on floor 1, nobody looks on floors 2 or 3, 2 people look on floor 4, 3 people look on floor 5, and 1 on floor 6.  You can represent this with the picture oo|||oo|ooo|o  where the o's represent masked (indistinguishable) people and the sticks separate the floors.

Comment: I got it. Your help was really appreciated, thank you!